# Boost 1.58 address-model has no effect

Tags: boost

This has happened to me on multiple platforms so far (Mac OS 10.10, Solaris Sparc 10, Debian 7). When I try to compile boost using b2, it chooses a default architecture. If I want to switch the architecture, nothing happens. Here are the commands I've tried. On Windows, this works fine.

**OSX**:

```
./b2 architecture=combined address-model=32_64 install --prefix=./osx/clang/universal
./b2 architecture=combined address-model=32_64
./b2 --architecture=combined --address-model=32_64 install --prefix=./osx/clang/universal
```

In this case its always trying to build 64 bit.

**Solaris/Linux**:

```
./b2 install --prefix=./<plaform>/<compiler>/<bitness> address-model=64
./b2 install address-model=64 --prefix=./<plaform>/<compiler>/<bitness>
./b2 address-model=64 install --prefix=./<plaform>/<compiler>/<bitness>
./b2 install --prefix=./<plaform>/<compiler>/<bitness> architecture=x86 address-model=64
```

In this case it is always building 32 bit.

I did delete and rebuild b2 using bootstrap.sh for each compiler and platform that I tried to build boost with.

Is there something else I need to change or set? I can't find any good documentation on this.

**Update**: It looks like `architecture=combined` for OSX means both powerpc and x86 chip architectures are suppoted. Tried without it, still no change. As well, even with the tag set to combined it still claims it's only building for x86 architectures. Found that information [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/bbv2/reference.html#bbv2.reference.rules) under the compilers section.

Answer (score 0):

If also you specify cxxflags=-m32 then that should work.